# How can I achieve this bottom sheet arc background in android using custom view, xml or any other alternative?

Tags: java, android, xml, kotlin, view

How can I achieve this bottom sheet curved arc design? Any thoughts on how to go about it building one using a custom view? [image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m5qHa.jpg)

Comment: You could try using motionlayout to re-create this view